# Undo git push to branch master

Tags: git

I did a mistake, I work on branch develop, but I did a git push to branch master. How can I undo that? Thanks!

```
git push origin c45f349cedfc1df51300a8ebb964088c305f2567:master
WARNING

Any access or any attempt to access this machine without permission is forbidden
and could be subject to criminal and civil penalties.

To protect this system from unauthorised use, viruses and to ensure that the
system is functioning properly, security systems have been installed.

Any unauthorised attempt to stop or bypass one of these security tools is
forbidden.

ATTENTION

Tout acces ou tentative d'acces non autorisee sur ce systeme est interdit
et sujet a des poursuites penales ou civiles.

Pour proteger ce systeme des acces frauduleux et des virus, et pour assurer son
bon fonctionnement, des systemes de securites ont ete installes.

Toute tentative non autorisee pour arreter ou contourner l'un de ces
dispositifs est interdite.
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.78 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@git.oad.exch.int:optiq/message-bus.git
   0ca786a..c45f349  c45f349cedfc1df51300a8ebb964088c305f2567 -> master
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reverse a commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381945/how-do-i-reverse-a-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. checkout to master

> git checkout master

2. View master last commit

> git log --oneline

3. reset to last commit

> git reset --hard lastcommit

4. force push origin master

> git push -f origin master:master

Comment: Can you add some explanation why this works or why is this recommended?

Comment: @DavidAngulo I am not suggest use any 'force' command, because it's show you are fault.